# BigQuery Fetch the Credentials again

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am using this code:

```
import pydata_google_auth
credentials = pydata_google_auth.get_user_credentials(
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'],
)
```

I have already logged in via OAuth before. Now I want to change the user credentials but it's taking from the old login only. It's not generating the URL again. How to force it to regenerate the URL again?

Answer (score 0):

by Default a credential file will be saved at `$HOME/.config/pydata/pydata_google_credentials.json` or `$APPDATA/.config/pydata/pydata_google_credentials.json` on Windows.

Use the following to not save it, and you will have to authenticate when you run it:

```py
import pydata_google_auth
credentials = pydata_google_auth.get_user_credentials(
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'], credentials_cache=pydata_google_auth.cache.NOOP
)
```